# asmx won't return JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, asmx

I've completely rewritten this old asmx service function but I still can't get it to return JSON.  It returns XML, even if I use ajax() and set the datatype and contenttype to json.  I'm trying to use this function with Jquery dataTables.  And I know there are tons of questions like this but all of them I've found are C# and I was unable to adapt them.

**up-to-date pastebin of full asmx file**: http://pastebin.com/swXKqgd4

**new code**

```
   <WebMethod()> _
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function rptPendingServerRequests() As Generic.List(Of request)
        Dim _conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim _dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim Sql As String = String.Empty
        Sql += "<My query here>"

        Try
            Dim _cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, _conn)
            _conn.Open()
            _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            If _dr.HasRows Then
                Dim s As request
                Dim c As New Generic.List(Of request)
                While _dr.Read
                    s = New request
                    With s
                        .requestID = _dr("request_id")
                        .status = _dr("status")
                        .requester = _dr("req_by_user_id")
                        .assignee = _dr("user_id")
                        .nextAction = _dr("description")
                    End With
                    c.Add(s)
                End While

                Return c
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            _conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Function
```

**New class**

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class request
    Private _requestID As Integer
    Public Property requestID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _requestID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _requestID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _requester As String
    Public Property requester() As String
        Get
            Return _requester
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _requester = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _requestDate As Date
    Public Property requestDate() As Date
        Get
            Return _requestDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _requestDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _status As Integer
    Public Property status() As Integer
        Get
            Return _status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _status = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _assignee As String
    Public Property assignee() As String
        Get
            Return _assignee
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _assignee = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _nextAction As String
    Public Property nextAction() As String
        Get
            Return _nextAction
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _nextAction = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

**Original Code**

```
<WebMethod()> _
<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Public Function rptPendingServerRequestsOld() As DataSet
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    sql = ""
    sql += "<MY query here>"

    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

**Client**

```
        $('#report').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'reportdata.asmx/rptPendingServerRequests'
        });
```

Comment: What is being returned by the call?

Comment: XML.  Even when I use Jquery's Ajax method and pass a JSON content and data type, I still get XML.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling this method from JS instead of

```
<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
```

use

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
```

attribute. Also don't forget to mark your WebService class with

```
<ScriptService()>
```

attribute.

Comment: Still get the same results.  Here is the FULL asmx file: http://pastebin.com/swXKqgd4

Comment: I am not familiar with DataTable, but can you make sure that your AJAX request is done via POST? If not, try one more modification for WebMethod attribute:  `<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet := true, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>`

Comment: The Test AJAX call I'm doing is using POST.  Adding the UseHttpGet didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line.

```
Public Function rptPendingServerRequests() As Generic.List(Of request)
```

to

```
Public Function rptPendingServerRequests() As String.
```